# Ruby on rails - Where SQL method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to get all the microposts where 'something' = true.

This code works fine

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts
    @titre = @user.nom
  end
end
```

But when I tried to make a where sql method this code doesn't work.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
      .
      .
      .
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @microposts = @user.microposts.where("something = 'true'")
        @titre = @user.nom
      end
    end
```

any idea ?

Comment: The problem may be that something is a boolean and not a string.

Answer (score 4):

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.where(something: true)
    @titre = @user.nom
 end
```

See [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions) or [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) for more info on narrowing the query scope.

Comment: @user1560922 - if the problem is solved, please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write like this:

```
Micropost.where(user_id: params[:id], something: true)
```

Comment: yes but on my users model: "has_many :microposts" will be useless then ?

Comment: What is the difference? Maybe it will be needed elsewhere.

Comment: Changing to `something: true` is a good suggestion, but there is no reason not to use `@user.microposts`.